# Как можно принять JSON?

Tags: php, c#, .net, битрикс

Подскажите пожалуйста как в `PHP` принимается `JSON`? Просто, я тут решил потестить в битриксе24 исходящие веб хуки написал API на `.net` но он почему-то не может ничего принял от битрикс, ну я и написал простую прогу которая отправляет `JSON` на API

```
var date = new
            {
                Value1="dsfgdfg",
                Value2="tyuotyugkljkmv"
            };
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(date));
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create();
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("Charset:utf8");
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            Stream datastream = request.GetRequestStream();
            datastream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            datastream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            var data = stream.ReadToEnd().Replace("null", "''");
            var statusCode = Convert.ToInt16(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode);
```

API в итоге нормально принимает `JSON`.

Ну и тогра я нашел код на `PHP` для исходящего веб хука и отправки в чат того что пришло

```
postToChat(print_r($_REQUEST, true));
function postToChat($message, $attach = array()) {
$queryUrl = 'https://xxxxxxx.bitrix24.ru/rest/1/xxxxxx/im.message.add.json';
$queryData = http_build_query(
    array(
        "USER_ID" => 1,
        "MESSAGE" => $message,
        "ATTACH" => $attach
    )
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $queryUrl,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $queryData,
));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

return json_decode($result, true);
}
```

Код то работает спокойно принимает все что приходит из битрикс, однако, когда я  обращаюсь к нему но через прогу на `.net` он ничего кроме `Array()` не выдает.

Я `PHP` ток начал изучать, подскажите почему вместо этого  `{Value1="dsfgdfg",Value2="tyuotyugkljkmv" }` я вижу это `Array()`.

Спасибо

Answer (score -1):

как пример

```
<?php

$array=['apple','orange','banana','strawberry'];
 $fun=json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
 echo $fun.'<br>';
$afun=json_decode($fun);
print_r($afun);

?>
```